# dual public IPs for same adsl connection?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, router, dyndns

I'm using a ZTE ADSL router to connect to the internet. I can use the internet without any trouble. but when i check my public ip in the router(192.168.1.1) it dispalys it as 100.68.40.XX under wan ip.
And when i check the public ip in my browser using googe or any other web site that displays something else. ex 112.134.33.XX.

why it shows two diff address at two seperate place for the same router at the same moment. and how dose i make the both the address same.
it is required to configure dyndns for some purpose

my router model is ZXV10 W300

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue by myself. IT cant have 2 public ip for the same device(router in my case} at the same time. The thing was the servise provider has issued me some generated ip and it is not a public ip. I was behind a NAT. So when i called them, they allowed my roter to get a real public ip and that solved the issue.
thanks